# JavaScript Scrolling list Downward

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Can anyone help me with this? I am trying to get the list to move downward rather than upward as you can see in the link below. Also, items begin to overlap when I try to have more than 4 items. Help or suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/gkTWC/48/

This is the code I currently am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $(".marqueeElement").each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.css("top", i);
          i += 60;
          doScroll($this);
    });
});

    function doScroll($ele) {
        var top = parseInt($ele.css("top"));
        if(top < -50) {
            top = 180;
            $ele.css("top", top);
        }
        $ele.animate({ top: (parseInt(top)-60) },600,'linear', function() {doScroll($(this))});
    }
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gkTWC/1129/

Comment: Thanks, I made some slight improvements as shown at this link, but I still can't get more than 4 items to rotate through.

http://jsfiddle.net/gkTWC/1131/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys. I'm a baller.

http://jsfiddle.net/gkTWC/1131/

```
if(top > 480) {
top = -60;
}
```